# Can't flip CGImage

Tags: iphone, core-animation

What i need to do is to flip a CGImageRef which is a conntents property of a CALayer from left to right. I've been googling thoroughly to find a way of directly flipping it but in wain. So what i decided to do is to flip an UIImage and then set its CGImage property as the contents for CALayer.

So what i did is:

```
 UIImage *src = [UIImage imageNamed:@"res/images/lizard.png"];
src = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:src.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRightMirrored];
UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:src];
[test setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:test];

[lizard.layer setContents:((id)test.image.CGImage)];
```

but it was in vain, the layer remained not flipped. what i did next is:

```
UIImage *src = [UIImage imageNamed:@"res/images/lizard.png"];
UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:src];
[test setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:test];
test.transform   = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
test.transform   = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);

[lizard.layer setContents:((id)test.image.CGImage)];
```

But unfortunately it still doesn't give me what i need. UIImageView named `test` is displayed as expected - it is flipped, but the contents of lizard.layer is not. How could it happen? 
Can you help me?

1) Is there a normal way to flip CALayer's contents?

2) If not then how do i flip CGImageRef to set contents correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have applied transform to test imageview not its image. So when you assign the image to some other unflipped layer you can't expect flipped output.

Apply your transforms to lizard.layer . you would get it.

```
[lizard.layer  setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
[lizard.layer setAffineTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0)];
```

Comment: How do i apply transform to lizard.layer?

Comment: You can assign transforms to CAlayer's using this methos- (void)setAffineTransform:(CGAffineTransform)m;

Comment: it works but not how i need it to work. it flips the image but it flips it... i don't know how to describe... the image not just flipped, it is vanishing from from top and bottom to the center and then appearing frome the center to bottom and top, really difficult to explain, but it doesn't work like i need.

Comment: can you post images of what you need exactly.?.

Comment: i can post image but i can't post movement of the flipping image. if you apply setAffineTransform to a layer with any image you'll see what i'm talking about

Comment: Not a prob. Just post what you want alone.